# Passing declare-styleable XML attributes into another viewgroup

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to "inherit" [declare-styleable](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html) attributes into other (child) views?

Can `gauge:visibility` be referenced declaratively in `android:visibility`?

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:gauge="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.MainActivity">

    <com.example.gauges.GradientCircleGauge
        android:id="@+id/gcg_gauge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        gauge:visibility="visible"
    </com.example.gauges.GradientCircleGauge>

</RelativeLayout>
```

gradient_circle_gauge.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="100"
        android:visibility="????"
        android:progress="100"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circle_gauge_background" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Shouldn’t GradientCircleGauge class take care of this?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Ideally yes, however there are some properties that do not expose methods in the classes and cannot be updated. For example android:thickness in GradientDrawable.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you want `gauge:visibility` to do?

Comment: I want the GradientCircleGauge to be able to control the ProgressBar's `android:visibility` attribute from the XML declaration. Is it possible?